# Some small advertising on Reddit

Tags: discussion

it's not a question but rather a very small announcement.

Yesterday I asked an obvious Kerbal Space Program-related question on the site since I assumed it might be related to the site.

Then I post it in the KSP subreddit of Reddit. [Now it's on "frontpage".](http://www.reddit.com/r/KerbalSpaceProgram/) I hope this very small post can help  making this site more popular, since it's a great source of a lot of space exploration related fields and topics.

Comment: Very nice. I think it's a great idea if we can get more exposure on other websites; whether through Twitter, Hacker News, Reddit, etc. We should have no problem growing our user base as interest in the technology is growing. However, we probably don't want to be flooded with KSP specific questions, although I really enjoyed the [recent one](http://space.stackexchange.com/questions/4505/how-realistic-is-kerbal-space-program) about how realistic it is.

Comment: Funny, I just tried to create a post to r/Space about this Stack Exchange, but it appears to have been removed by the moderators. I never considered that this site is in competition with r/Space.

Comment: @Stu I could posts question in r/Space, but they had mixed reception.

Comment: @Stu That subreddit had a solicitation post from when this site was in Area51. The policy is probably that duplicate posts will be removed without warning, and I've never known Reddit moderators to give any deletion notification beyond insults.